# When I select items in a collection view, it selects other items

Tags: swift

when I select one item in a collection view, another item further down gets selected. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Category3Cell {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.8674157229, blue: 0.4739984274, alpha: 1)
            recommends.append(cell.categoryKey)
            print("select \(recommends)")
            cell.isSelected = true
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Category3Cell {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
            recommends = recommends.filter(){$0 != cell.categoryKey}
            print("deselect \(recommends)")
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are being reused when you scroll.

You must therefore make sure to reset things like background color in your `func cellForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath)`.